# How to display an IP address in HTA

Tags: php, html, ip

Answering below to share some information I've recently learned. Feel free to contribute to it

Sometimes this just comes in handy. I'm a beginner so this was nice to know some more basic functions

Comment: This question has nothing specific to .hta.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayMyIP.hta

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub Window_onLoad
    WindowLeft = (window.screen.availWidth - 350)  
WindowTop  = (window.screen.availHeight - 130)
window.moveTo WindowLeft, WindowTop
    window.resizeTo 386,144
End Sub 
</SCRIPT>
<style>
html,
body,
iframe {
width: 95%;
height: 80%;
}
</style>
<body>
<iframe src="http://net-paste.com/ip.php" style="border:1px blue solid;" 
name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="yes" align="center" height = "100%" 
width = "100%">
</iframe>
 </body>
```

(You don't need this as it's already linked in the script above)
Here's Ip.php

```
 <?php
 $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 echo "<h4> Your IP address is:<code> $ipaddress </code> </h4>";
 ?>
```